# Time Machine: should I partition a 500GB disk?

Tags: time-machine

I was considering using Time Machine and I was wondering if creating a 50 GB partition on a disk of 500 GB for it make sense.

Comment: Using the same disk for system and time machine makes sense only if you want to be able to retrieve deleted files on a laptop. Combining this with an external backup of both partitions would be wise.

Comment: @mouviciel That's exactly what I have explained in the comments below. I should have added to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you could do this, although 50 GB is far too small for most any use these days.

The point of concern I think should be raised here is that you look to be hosting both files and backups on the same drive. When (not if—*when*) the hard drive fails, you will lose both. You would be much better off in the long run keeping the files and backups on separate drives.

**UPDATE (based on comments):** The rule of thumb that I've seen for deciding on a drive size to house a Time Machine back up is at least a 2:1 ratio of the drive to be backed up (so a 500GB would mean a 1 TB TM-hosting drive), and I don't see why that general rule couldn't be followed here.

Look at the data volume of the folders you intended to back up, double that, and that's the size partition you go with. If Time Machine requires a minimum that's below what you calculated, just double the size of that for your partition and off you go.

Either way, I don't think you're going to find a hard number here.

Comment: @Philip Regan yeah.. that's true and a good point.. thanks. I have a backup for that (I do it manually...). However I wanted to use time machine just to recover files (such as when I erroneously save some text file and I lose code.. etc). What do you think a good ratio should be ? (500GB hard disk)

Comment: If you already have another drive for hosting files, then why partition this new drive? Just leave it as is.

Comment: @Philip Regan: Because I need automatic backups on short-time period mistakes.. such as overwriting wrong files etc. In other words, I want an immediate backup, (every time I save a file)

Comment: Right. I get that part, I use TM at home. What I think is confusing a lot of people is why you feel the need to partition the disk. Because based on your comments, you don't.

Comment: @Philip Regan OK, so.. well let's say I exclude all folders and I decide to backup only few of them (mainly text files).. how big should the partition be ? What about 50GB ?

Comment: Don't partition. If you all you are going to be doing is using this new drive as a back up and not manually any files on it per your other comments, then there is no good reason to partition the drive. Just plug it in, point TM to it, and let it fly.

Comment: @Philip Regan So again, the point is that I can't bring the drive to the office, library, etc.. the idea was to have a backup system on my laptop. That was the point of the partition.

Comment: So, this is an internal disk, not an external one. Maybe that wasn't clear in the question or a bad assumption on my part, sorry.

Comment: @Philip Regan Ok cool, I will try then to use it. And let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're interested in using the 50GB partition for Time Machine? Keep in mind that Time Machine keeps multiple copies of changed files - it's not just a single back up of your drive. Your backup drive should be at least a couple times larger than the stuff you're backing up, so Time Machine can keep a decent backlog of changes beyond just the most recent.

That said, Time Machine will fill the disk with backlog changes until it can no longer fit them, so as long as you have enough space for a "most recent" backup, Time Machine will be happy.

Comment: @Nick ok thanks, so let's say I have a 500GB hard disk (and I don't use big files.. just work and programming..) what a good ratio for a partition ? what about 300GB for my files and 200GB for time machine ?

Comment: That depends entirely on how big your "work and programming" files are. Maybe you work in Final Cut Pro (big files) or just textedit (small files)?

Comment: @Nick ok. No.. just web and mobile development (no big files). Is not possible to decide which folders to backup right ? It would be great

Comment: You can choose to *not* back up certain folders, which could be most of your drive if you choose.

Comment: @Nick ok cool, so then.. this change everything, because If I only backup text files folders.. I just need few GB for the back up right ?

Comment: Yes, but if you're only backing up a couple folders of text files and images I'd use a different solution - DropBox comes to mind.

Comment: @Nick Do you mean dropbox.com service ? Is it keeping track of the old files ? I thought dropbox is sync the content and lose the old versions when it is updated.

Comment: Yes, you can add a (paid) package on to the free version that backs up unlimited versions of your files.

Comment: @Nick So, clearly I don't want to pay, what's the point if I can do it with Time Machine ? I guess now, the best thing is just to test it... and I will come back here to say how it is going.

Comment: You pay with your time. How much is it worth to you to set up dropbox and have it just work, rather than repartitioning and setting up time machine, excluding files, and moving everything safely when you get a new computer? More than $40?

Answer (score 0):

TimeMachine already places backups inside a folder on the hard disk, so it will not create a mess on that drive.

The only reason you should create a partition is if you would not like TimeMachine to use up as much disk space as it needs. Every time a file changes it will create a new copy of it in the backup, and only pruning old versions once the disk is full. If you create a small partition it will restrict the backup to that size.

Answer (score 0):

OK, my question is simple and related; should I absolutely partition a 2T external drive where I want to keep time machine backup for a 250GB macbook and 50 GB of photos (mostly jpeg). & videos?  If it's highly recommended to do so, why?  Thanks!  (and I read the dated reply on losing the data, but that's a risk of any external disk, whether one or more).